# If i download a file straight to the flash drive, will it go directly there?

Tags: hard-drive, usb, download

So suppose I want to download something from the browser (Save as). The download prompt appears and I'm choosing the location to be somewhere on my flash USB drive. Now, will it go directly to the USB drive or maybe will it go to some kind of a temporary files folder on the HDD first and from there to the USB? And if the latter option is the case, where is it stored and does the file leave some traces on HDD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which OS? But "it depends".
Download a really big 5GB file (https://fastest.fish/test-files) and see for yourself if it creates a download file on the USB or if the file appears after it has been downloaded. On my Mac it creates a temp file with extension .partial in the folder I download it to and when finished it gets the correct extension. It does not get saved to a temp location and then transferred.

Comment: On windows it seems to be similar, with partial file already in the drive's folder while downloading and right after the process is finished, the file's there with proper extension. So it seems like it's the direct process.

Comment: @Tuvrai Browsers often save the partial download to their user working directory within `%LocalAppData%`, with a placeholder in the final storage location, moving the completed file there once downloaded, as browsers usually have built-in download managers that have simultaneous download streams _(e.g. a downloaded file will be in multiple chunks that are collated into a single file when the download is finalized)_